# How to String Concatenation in Entity SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-sql

A very quick question

SQL:

```
SELECT VALUE ROW( ('#' + CAST(pack.PackageID as Edm.String)) as PackageID) From ProductPackage
```

It show error, edm.String not found, I also try String or Varchar,still error.

I have read that reference but no help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386905.aspx

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a documentation problem. Try `System.String` instead of `Edm.String`.

Comment: I want to kiss you right on the lips!  This has been driving me nuts!