# Entity query 'Like' doesn't support int column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-like, entity-sql

I am trying to implement the `Like` operator by using the entity framework query. But it seems `Like` doesn't appear to be supported on an `int` column.

Here is my query:

```
using (ObjectContext ctx = new ObjectContext(gbcDbConnection.eObjqueryConnection))
{
    string result = " Select ";
    result += "       master_factory.FACTORY_ID, master_factory.FACTORY_NAME,  ";
    result += "       case when master_factory.FACTORY_TYPE ='"  
           + gbvArticleVarieble.FactoryTypeExterIni+"' then '" 
           + gbvArticleVarieble.FactoryTypeExter+"' else '" 
           + gbvArticleVarieble.FactoryTypeInter+"' end as factory_type ";

    result += " FROM  ";
    result += "     LEWREDBEntities.[MASTER_FACTORY] as master_factory  ";


    result += " WHERE ";
    result += "      (master_factory.FACTORY_TYPE = @factoryType1 or master_factory.FACTORY_TYPE =@factoryType2) and master_factory.STATUS<>@status";


    if (searchVal != "")
    {
         result += "      AND master_factory.[FACTORY_ID]  LIKE '%' + @searchVal + '%' ";
    }



    ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> query = ctx.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(result);
    query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("status", gbcDBVariable.DeleteIni));
    query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("factoryType1",gbvArticleVarieble.FactoryTypeExterIni ));
    query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("factoryType2", gbvArticleVarieble.FactoryTypeInterIni));
    if (searchVal != "")
    {
        query.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("searchValue", searchVal));

    }
    if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
    {
        query.ToTraceString();
    }
```

As you see, the Factory id is integer data type. When I execute it, it returns an error:

> LIKE arguments must be of string type. Near member access expression

Did anyone else try this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use CAST, I'm not familiar with ESQL but:

AND CAST(master_factory.[FACTORY_ID] as System.String)  LIKE '%' + @searchVal + '%'

This link gets all mushy:
[How to String Concatenation in Entity SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323842/how-to-string-concatenation-in-entity-sql)

this is more formal:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399172.aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself:

> LIKE arguments must be of string type.

That's your answer :)